# Deriving $-\vec{\nabla}V$ from $V_b-V_a=-\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, work, voltage

I'm trying to understand how to derive $-\vec{\nabla}V$ from $V_b-V_a=-\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$. I'm not really familiar with the gradient operator, I know how to compute it and I know that $\vec{\nabla}=\hat{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\hat{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

From that formula, I guess that writing $\vec{\nabla}f$ would give as result a vector whose direction depends on the increase/decrease of $f$ in the $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions (it would point towards the positive $x$ direction, positive $y$ direction and negative $z$ direction if $f$ is increasing in the $x$ and $y$ direction, and $f$ is decreasing in the $z$ direction), and the length of the vector in those directions depends on how much $f$ it's increasing and decreasing in those directions. I don't know if this is correct, I've never read anything about the $\vec{\nabla}$ operator, and the formula above is all I was given.

The book I'm reading derives that equation on the following page as follows.

[image]

[image]

The footnote is as follows.

[image]

---

> What I don't understand is how is $-\vec{E}\cdot d \vec{l}=-E_ldl$? The dot product $\vec{E}\cdot d \vec{l}$ is equivalent to $E_xdx+E_ydy_+E_zdz$ or equivalent to $(E)(dl)cos(\theta)$ but I don't get how these last two are equivalent to $-E_ldl$. And I don't get how equation (8) is equal equation (9), which is equal to $-\vec{\nabla}V$.

Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be that this is just a question of semantics. The statement $$\mathbf{E}\cdot\text{d}\ell = E_\ell\, \text{d}\ell$$ is not telling you anything new: it's just writing the dot product in a different way. Just as $E_x$ represents the "amount" of Electric Field in the $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ direction, $E_\ell$ represents the amount of the field in the $\text{d}\mathbf{\hat{\ell}}$ direction, whatever that direction might be. For example, it should be clear to you that:

$$\mathbf{E}\cdot \text{d} \mathbf{x} = E_x \text{d}x.$$

So by the very definition of the dot product, $\mathbf{E}\cdot\text{d}\mathbf{\ell} = E_\ell \text{d}\ell$, since that's what the dot product is doing: it's picking out the component of the electric field along the direction given by the $\text{d}\hat{\ell}$ vector.

If you wish to use your standard definition of $$\mathbf{E}\cdot \text{d} \mathbf{\ell} = E \,\cos\theta\,\, \text{d}\ell,$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{E}$ and $\text{d}\mathbf{\ell}$, then the quantity $E\cos\theta$ is precisely what one would call $E_\ell$. i.e. $$E_\ell = E \cos{\theta}.$$

(Of course, keep in mind that as you integrate over a curve, the angle between $\mathbf{E}$ and $\text{d}\ell$ could change, and so in general, $\theta$ is a function of $\ell$ and not a constant.)

---

As to how Equations (8) and (9) are related, the author simply chooses the (arbitrary) direction $\ell$ respectively in Equation (8) to be $x$, $y$, and $z$. This leads to Equation (9). The partial derivatives appear since you're only varying one coordinate at a time, keeping the others fixed.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't think about it thank you! Can I ask you if what i wrote about the gradient operator is correct?

Comment: Well it's worded a *little* confusingly. The main thing that you may not have understood is that the gradient is a vector *field*, meaning that it gives a different vector at different points in space. At each point in space, the direction of this vector is the direction of steepest slope. Keep in mind that a vector cannot point in more than one direction: it will point in the *net* direction of steepest change. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, for example, your statement *it would point towards the positive $x$ direction, positive $y$ direction and negative $z$ direction if: $f$ is increasing in the $x$ and $y$ direction, and $f$ is decreasing in the $z$ direction* is not correct. Firstly, the gradient (at some point) only points in one direction, and its magnitude would also depend on how fast or slow the function is changing in each direction. So to know which way it points, you also need to know the "steepness" along $x$, $y$, and $z$...

Comment: yeah maybe i didn't explain myself well, with "it would point towards the positive x direction, positive y direction and negative z direction" i mean that it is a vector for with components positive, positive negative respectively, like (+3,+4,-2), and if that's the gradient of $f$ that would mean that $f$ is changing more rapidly in the $y$ direction. I think this is what you said as well right?

Comment: Yes. In the example you've given, the change is the most along $y$ **as compared to** along $x$ and $z$, yes. However, keep in mind that in this case the direction of the gradient will not be purely along $y$. You can compute that direction from the vector you have given, and *that* will be the direction along which the change is steepest, even more than along $y$. (I find that in such problems, it's best to first develop an intuition in 2D, and only then move to 3D :) )

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the gradient does give the direction of increase.

If we know that any component of electric field $E_l$ is equal to the negative of the rate of change of electric potential with respect to distance in that direction. One can simply rewrite the vector field $\vec{E}$ as the vector sum of all its orthogonal components in terms of orthonormal  basis vectors $\vec{E}=E_xe_x+E_ye_y+E_ze_z$. Then of course since the negative of your electric field can be expressed as a gradient of some potential function $V$, you get $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ as a result.